# Map does not render completely in d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am creating a globe on which I plot a number of locations. Each location is identified with a small circle and provides information via a tooltip when the cursor hovers over the circle.

My problem is the global map renders incompletely most of the time. That is various countries do not show up and the behavior of the code changes completely at this point. I say most of the time because about every 5th time i refresh the browser it does render completely. I feel like I either have a hole in my code or the JSON file has a syntax problem that confuses the browser.

btw: I have the same problem is FF, Safari, and Chrome. I am using v3 of D3.js

Here is the rendering code:

```
d3.json("d/world-countries.json", function (error, collection) {
    map.selectAll("path")
        .data(collection.features)
        .enter()
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("class", "country")
        .attr("d", path)
        .append("svg:title")
        .text( function(d) { 
            return d.properties.name; });
});
track = "countries";
d3.json("d/quakes.json", function (error, collection) {
    map.selectAll("quakes")
        .data(collection.features)
        .enter()
        .append("svg:path")       
        .attr("r", function (d) {
            return impactSize(d.properties.mag);
        })
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
            return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[0];
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[1];
        })
        .attr("class", "quake") 
        .on("mouseover", nodehi)
        .on("mouseout", nodelo) 
        .attr("d", path)
                .append("svg:title")
        .text( function(d) {
            var tip = d.properties.description + " long "+ (d.geometry.coordinates)[0] + " lat " + (d.geometry.coordinates)[1];
            return tip
        });
});
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated...

Comment: Are your JSON files very large? It's really hard to tell what's going on without a complete example.

Comment: The world-countries file seems pretty bit to me. Not sure what is acceptable here - 253kb. The quakes file is quite a bit smaller - 31kb.

Comment: I ran both files through JSONLint - I assume that assures some level of syntax checking. Since I am very new at this I will be glad to do my own research and testing. It does seem strange that it is not consistent.

Comment: Could it be [this](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/issues/10)?

Comment: Could be similar issue, but Bermuda is not in my JSON file. I will look for a different version of my JSON file to see if I have corrupted some other country. The "non rendered" countries are consistent so maybe I will focus on them.

Comment: I just found one difference. The"non rendered" countries are all MultiPolygon in the JSON vs Polygon for those that render consistently.

Comment: Strike that. All of the "non rendered" countries are MultiPolygon but not all MultiPolygon are "non rendered"...

Comment: After doing more research I am going to look at the code instead of the JSON file. I have tested my world-countries.json file here - (http://bl.ocks.org/johan/raw/1431429/) and it works every time.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what it is. Nest your `d3.json` calls, i.e. `d3.json("d/world-countries.json", function (error, collection) { d3.json("d/quakes.json", function (error1, collection1) { }); });`.

Comment: Thanks so much, that is exactly it! Can you explain why it would behave so erratically?

Comment: Sure, I'll post an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this behaviour is that you're doing two asynchronous calls (to `d3.json`) that are not independent of each other because of the way you're selecting elements and binding data to them. By the nature of asynchronous calls, you can't tell which one will finish first, and depending on which one does, you see either the correct or incorrect behaviour.

In both handler functions, you're appending `path` elements. In the first one (for the world file), you're also selecting `path` elements to bind data to them. If the other call finished first, there will be `path` elements on the page. These will be matched to the data that you pass to `.data()`, and hence the `.enter()` selection won't contain all the elements you're expecting. This is not a problem if the calls finish the other way because you're selecting `quake` elements in the other handler.

There are several ways to fix this. You could either assign identifying classes to all your paths (which you're doing already) and change the selectors accordingly -- in the first handler, do `.selectAll("path.country")` and in the second `.selectAll("path.quake")`.

Alternatively, you could nest the two calls to `d3.json` such that the second one is only made once the first one is finished. I would do both of those to be sure when elements are drawn, but for performance reasons you may still want to make the two calls at the same time.